# Multi-Dimensional array, returning wrong result

Tags: php, arrays

I have a multi-dimensional array (There is more than one item in "data" but i'm just showing one for this question):

```
Array
(
    [data] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [to] => Array
                        (
                            [data] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [name] => fake name
                                            [id] => 668071477234
                                        )

                                    [1] => Array
                                        (
                                            [name] => fake name
                                            [id] => 1345556711
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                    [updated_time] => 2012-12-24T23:46:26+0000
                    [id] => 327424994013537
                )
        )

)
```

I am trying to loop thru the array and determine if the id matches a variable sent from $_REQUEST, and if it does, I only want to return the "updated_time" value of the iteration.

Here's what I have but the date is always wrong, and doesn't match the proper iteration:

```
    foreach($userOutbox['data'] as $outbox){
        foreach($outbox['to']['data'] as $user){
            if($user['id'] == $_REQUEST['facebook_id']){                                           

                      $last_message_date = $outbox['updated_time'];
            }
        }
    }
```

It's late and my eyes and brain are not helping me.  Can anyone give me any direction?

Comment: Looks fine as far as I can tell, although it's late here as well. Try printing out some debug info, like the request id to make sure it's what you're expecting, as well as the id it finds.

Comment: this code is working. working code example http://codepad.viper-7.com/OV7D58

Comment: If the code works on the codepad, and you're sure it's not working for you, then the only difference seems to be the $_REQUEST (it's hard coded in the codepad). Like I said before, double check and make sure it's what you are expecting.

Comment: Ok, the fix was a very simple one: just added break 2; after the variable was found.  Breaks out of both foreach loops so that $last_message_date isn't overwritten from another iteration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the solution that worked for me, just added `break 2;`  Thanks for your help:

```
foreach($userOutbox['data'] as $outbox){
    foreach($outbox['to']['data'] as $user){
        if($user['id'] == $_REQUEST['facebook_id']){                                           
           $last_message_date = $outbox['updated_time'];
           break 2;
        }
    }
}
```